# Метод Виолы-Джонса. Как именно происходит обучение классификатора?

Tags: алгоритм, машинное-зрение

Прочитал несколько статей на эту тему, в том числе https://habr.com/ru/post/133826/
Вроде понял в отдельности этапы (типа что такое признаки Хаара, интегральные отображения, бустинг), но не понятно, как именно происходит обучение классификатора. Например, у нас есть 10000 изображений с  нужным нам объектом (лицом, к примеру), и еще 100000 изображений, где не известно что находится (все они подписаны, типа есть лицо - нет лица). Смысл алгоритма, как я понял, состоит в том, чтобы многоуровневым отсечением, проходясь по изображению, только те элементы изображения, которые прошли все уровни, принимались за искомые объекты, а то что точно не является отсекалось первыми уровнями(слабыми классификаторами, из которых состоит один сильный). Я не понял как обучать эти слабые классификаторы? Что нужно давать на вход алгоритму, чтобы первый слабый классификатор верно отработал, и что последующим?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде понял. Допустим, нас есть для окна 24 на 24 - 160 000 различных признаков Хаара. Мы проходимся по всем изображениям (10000 лиц и 10000 не лиц), и ищем тот признак, что дает наилучший результат. После чего добавляем ему вес в соответсвии с тем, сколько он определил правильно и не правильно, и те примеры что он определил неправильно определяем как сложные, и назначаем для следующей итерации им веса побольше. В результате получается один большой классификатор, с маленькими классификаторами, каждому из которых задан определенный вес (типа как порог срабатывания).
В методе Виола-Джонс как я понял, классификаторы ставятся друг за другом, причем сначала те, что очень хорошо реагируют на изображения с лицом (с вероятностью 0.99) и вероятность ложно-положительных срабатываний у них может быть где то 0.3, для того чтобы в первую очередь отсеивались те фрагменты что точно лицами не являются. Таким образом точность достигается весьма большая.
Единственный вопрос для меня теперь в том, как мы определяем веса. Но вроде это уже зависит от реализации. Ну и получается нам нужно выбирать классификаторы таким образом, чтобы они главное отбирали все лица ( или 0.99 всех лиц), остальное менее важно.